What's the best way to send data from activity to fragments
So my question is simple. I have two activities (splash and main) 3 fragments will be placed on the main activity. i want to fetch data from api on the splash screen and display the fetched data on one of the fragments. how can i do that? whats the best way?
ive tried to send the data with intent to the main activity and then send it again with fragment set arguments. but i think thats not really a good way to handle this situation.
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Data", new Gson().toJson(dataList));

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Data", getIntent().getStringExtra("Data"));

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();;

        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_screen, homeFragment).commit();

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String stringData = bundle.getString("Data");

        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Data>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<Data> dataList = new Gson().fromJson(stringData, type);


"i want to fetch data from api on the splash screen" - do you want to do that though? What happens if there's an error? A splash screen is generally there to wait for the app to initialize and launch the first activity - not to wait around for a network request that could take forever or fail. Instead of fetching in splash and having to send all the data over to the main activity, just fetch it in the main activity directly (with a loading spinner and proper error handling).

there are 2-3 ways to access data in fragment from activity . we are use it according to our needs
1. you can directly access parent activity data .This solution integrates tight coupling between your activity and Fragment
Activity
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private String myString = "hello";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ...
    }

    public String getMyData() {
        return myString;
    }
}

Fragment

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
        String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
        return view;
    }
}

2.
Save Data in application class variables and access it in fragment from application class
3
Pass data between activity to frametn using arguments.
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String myMessage = "Stackoverflow";
        bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
        FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
        fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_single, fragInfo);
        transaction.commit();


But most of the developers are using 3rd way to passing data between
activity to fragment

